# Stale NFS file handle on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, nfs

I'm running Kubuntu 13.10, and I have a network attached storage device (HP Mediavault).  Usually, but not always, when I shut down the shutdown gets stuck on the message "Stale NFS file handle".  The fstab entry for the device is:

```
hpmediavault:/shares/Volume1/FileShare /mnt/mediavault nfs auto,users,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,_netdev,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

How can I prevent this blockage?